# Internal Server Error 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, google-chrome-extension

I got code like that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.facebook.com/ajax/groups/members/remove.php?group_id=1383973975234677&uid=100001311621338', 
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status); 
            alert(xhr.responseText); 
            alert(thrownError);
            }
    });
});
```

Of course I got admin rights on this group. Trying to remove user from Facebook group by AJAX request that "Remove" Facebook button is using and it is giving me error 500. How can I fix it? Thanks from above.

Comment: there is no api function to remove users from a group. you are not supposed to automate this by hijacking functionality from facebook.com.

Comment: So I have to get like every one element that leeds to removing user and use .click() function?

Comment: no, you have to do that manually, on facebook

Comment: No I don't. I will just write the script clicking stuff for me, by .click() function. Like automatization macro.

Answer (score 0):

The 500 HTTP response means the server encountered an unexpected condition and it was not able to fulfill the request.

This is most likely an internal issue with the facebook servers. The best you can do is contact facebook about it.